# Is there a CUDA equivalent of native_recip() in OpenCL?

Tags: cuda, opencl, porting

OpenCL has a built-in function named [`native_recip`](https://man.opencl.org/recip.html):

> ```
> gentype native_recip(gentype x);
> ```
>
> `native_recip` computes reciprocal over an implementation-defined range. The maximum error is implementation-defined.
>
> The vector versions of the math functions operate component-wise. The description is per-component.
>
> The built-in math functions are not affected by the prevailing rounding mode in the calling environment, and always return the same value as they would if called with the round to nearest even rounding mode.

Is there an equivalent to this function in CUDA?

Comment: __frcp_xx. Look at there intrinsic section in the math library documentation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As noted in comments, it's [`__frcp_rn()`](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-math-api/group__CUDA__MATH__INTRINSIC__SINGLE.html) for `float`'s and [`__drcp_rn()`](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-math-api/group__CUDA__MATH__INTRINSIC__DOUBLE.html) for `double`'s; and an implementation for vector types (e.g. `float4`) such that frcp/drcp is applied elementwise.

Note: "rcp" is short for "reciprocal" and "rn" is for the rounding mode ["round to nearest even"](https://blogs.sas.com/content/iml/2019/11/11/round-to-even.html).